# Want a recommendation letter, but the professor passed away

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, europe, death

I am in the process of collecting recommendations for my PhD.

I was the best-performing student in final exams on three different courses, all given by a single professor. (The results of the exams are anonymized and published for a short period in my university.) These were the courses related to the fields I want to do research in.
There is nothing else this professor could have written about me - I didn't do any research in their group.

Sadly, the professor passed away after a short and severe illness last month.

Is there any way I can get a recommendation letter which acknowledges that I was the best student in these courses? Would another professor write that, given the death of the professor in question?

Comment: Maybe ask the department chair, who would have access to your records ?

Comment: was there a TA?

Comment: can you just put this info to your cover letter/CV/statement of whatever?

Comment: When is the app due?

Comment: It's due in a few months. There were different TA's. The anonymized data for most of the courses is not public anymore, but the professors usually keep it somewhere, for purposes of recommendation letters actually. I don't know about the late professor.

Comment: I would really have liked to have this included in a recommendation letter, otherwise one of my letters will look really bland - "generic strong student, never met them".

Answer (score 6):

Your best letters will come from professors who know more about you than that you did well in their courses. I hope you have some of those.

You could say in a cover letter that your exams in this persons courses were tops in each, based on anonymized department reports. I doubt that you'd be required to provide evidence for that.

Comment: Of course my other letter will be more personal and better. However, it's not that I had an A, which is sadly not remarkable, it's that I was the best (out of >100) people each time, in courses in similar topics. Everyone I talked to says it could matter a lot.

Comment: Two is the minimum number of letters. I am able to obtain exactly one personalized letter.

Comment: Perhaps your other more personal and better letter can include a paragraph in which that writer talks about your top performance in these three courses. You could ask about that.

Comment: Not sure if the first letter writer even knew the late professor (they were in a similar research area, but at different institutions), but I can try.

Comment: It seems this professor would not have written a terribly good reference letter as he or she would simply have restated what's already on your transcript.  You must find a better referee.